# Run a macro using VBS on already opened excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I would like to run a macro on an Excel using VBS code. My Excel will be always open. I am using below code for that.

Excel: main.xlsm,  macro name: Inc

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\Main.xlsm", 0, False)
xlApp.Run "Inc"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

The problem is whenever I run the code, it looks like the Excel trying to open in read only mode. As soon as the VBS runs, I am getting "save changes window" and saving the sheet as a copy.

I would like to save the changes on the same sheet rather than saving it as a new copy.

Answer (score 2):

Excel lets you save a copy because you create a new instance of `Application` object, so you open the workbook again in read-only mode. To get a reference to `Application` object of the particular running instance of Excel with already opened workbook you should use the following lines:

```vb
Set xlBook = GetObject("E:\Main.xlsm")
Set xlApp = xlBook.Application
```

instead of

```vb
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\Main.xlsm", 0, False)
```

Then you just need to save that workbook with `.Save`.

Comment: still its asking to save the changes whenever i run the code

Comment: @acr use `.Save` method before closing, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Instance with `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, also the `WB` is then opened twice. Easiest fix, if you just close the `WB` before executing your code, then it should work fine. Also when closing use `xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True`, no prompt should appear then.